# StringBuilder vs. String.Concat, C#

Tags: c#, .net, строки

**Update: Мои тесты были неправильные. StringBuilder выигрывает даже при объединении 5 строк**

Я сравнил производительность StringBuilder и String.Concat c разным количеством строк, учитывая время на создание объекта StringBuilder.

При объединении 5 строк String.Concat всегда быстрее, иногда в 10 раз
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При объедении 10 строк String.Concat всегда быстрее, иногда в 10 раз
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При объединении 20 строк String.Concat всегда быстрее, иногда в 10 раз 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ли смысл использовать StringBuilder для объединения маленького количества строк? Вроде объект StringBuilder сам по себе отнимает больше ресурсов, чем 20 строк.

Код, который использовался для теста:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int countOfStrings = 20;
        string[] stringsToMerge = new string[countOfStrings];

        for (int i = 0; i < countOfStrings; i++)
        {
            stringsToMerge[i] = "stringN" + i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Count of strings:" + countOfStrings);

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan ts;
        stopWatch.Start();
        stopWatch.Stop();

        stopWatch.Restart();
        string s = stringsToMerge[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < countOfStrings; i++)
        {
            s = string.Concat(s, stringsToMerge[i]);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("String.Concat ms:" + ts.TotalMilliseconds);

        stopWatch.Restart();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(stringsToMerge[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < countOfStrings; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(stringsToMerge[i]);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder ms:" + ts.TotalMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: Какой код выдал такие результаты? Добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @Zergatul добавил

Comment: А при объединении 2000 строк кто быстрее?

Comment: @mirypoko, тут еще зависит от размера входных строк, например, при таких строках: `stringsToMerge[i] = "stringNstringNstringNstringNstringNstringNstringNstringNstringNstringN" + i;` уже при количестве в 5 шт. `string` не выглядит лучше, чем `SB`, а при 20 уже безнадежно отстает

Comment: @Андрей с такой строкой при 5 объединениях на моем компьютере String.Concat все равно всегда быстрее, при 20 иногда быстрее, иногда нет, 50 на 50.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-sharp
стоит почитать

Comment: @gil9red при 2000 строк StringBuilder во много раз быстрее, но мой вопрос про относительное небольшое количество строк.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я исправил ваш код. Во-первых, перед тестированием скорости, все методы нужно "прогреть". При первом вызове JIT-компилятор генерирует машинный код с IL и это занимает некоторое время. Во-вторых, не нужно тестировать одну итерацию, так как случайное событие в ОС может исказить результат. Во-третьих, вы передаете странное значение, в конструктор `StringBuilder`. При его использовании заведомо создается маленький размер буфера, который будет расширяться несколько раз. Для максимальной производительности, если есть возможность, вы должны задавать размер буфера, который не будет менятся.

И не забывайте запускать в `Release`, а не в `Debug`.

В исправленном варианте (не трогал конструктор):

```
Count of strings:5
String.Concat ms:1097.4772
StringBuilder ms:1294.881

Count of strings:10
String.Concat ms:2848.4845
StringBuilder ms:1970.4477
```

Уже на 10 выигрывает `StringBuilder`.

```
const int countOfStrings = 5;
const int iterations = 10000000;
string[] stringsToMerge = new string[countOfStrings];

for (int i = 0; i < countOfStrings; i++)
{
    stringsToMerge[i] = "stringN" + i;
}

// компилируем IL в машинный код
string.Concat("123", "qwe");
var x = new StringBuilder(40);
x.Append("123qwe");

Console.WriteLine("Count of strings:" + countOfStrings);

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
TimeSpan ts;
stopWatch.Start();
stopWatch.Stop();

stopWatch.Restart();
for (int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++)
{
    string s = stringsToMerge[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < countOfStrings; i++)
    {
        s = string.Concat(s, stringsToMerge[i]);
    }
}
stopWatch.Stop();
ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine("String.Concat ms:" + ts.TotalMilliseconds);

stopWatch.Restart();
for (int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(stringsToMerge[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < countOfStrings; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(stringsToMerge[i]);
    }
}
stopWatch.Stop();
ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder ms:" + ts.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Если же я переделаю использование `StringBuilder`, то он выигрывает уже на 5 строках:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(100);
for (int i = 0; i < countOfStrings; i++)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(stringsToMerge[i]);
}

Count of strings:5
String.Concat ms:1053.0082
StringBuilder ms:699.7725
```

Comment: Стоит ещё упомянуть, что запускать тесты нужно _вне_ Visual Studio.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 (Start without debugging) должно быть достаточно, или нет?

Comment: @Zergatul версию выпуска запускайте

Comment: @Zergatul: Угу, должно быть достаточно.

Comment: @Zergatul "выигрывает" с разницей в 1000 ms на 10 000 000 итераций практически означает "нет разницы что использовать, если ваша программа не занимается исключительно сложением миллиардов строк"

Comment: @VladD, @PashaPash, а чего бы не закрыть дубликатом? было ж уже`

Comment: @Grundy давайте ссылку. только я сначала ответ напишу

Comment: @PashaPash, я уже флагнул на закрытие, в комментариях под вопросом

Comment: @PashaPash человека интересовало быстродействие, и почему в него `StringBuilder` "тормозил".

Comment: @Zergatul он у него тормозил из-за разогрева (что вы в своем ответе упомянули). вот только выводы человек сделали неправильные :)

Comment: @Grundy тут не совсем дубликат - вопрос вызван не проблемой, а неожиданными результатами сравнения (кривыми тестами)

Answer (score 6):

Даже если не принимать во внимание неправильность тестов - пусть вы провели более тщательное тестирование и выяснили, например, что на 10 строках результат следующий

```
Count of strings:10
String.Concat ms:2848.4845
StringBuilder ms:1970.4477
```

Какой вывод вы из этого делаете?

> StringBuilder выигрывает даже при объединении 5 строк

Какой реальный вывод стоит сделать из таких результатов?

**Нет ощутимой разницы между StringBuilder и String.Concat** в случаях, если ваша программа не занимается *исключительно* сложением миллиардов строк. Во всех остальных случаях вы не заметите разницы. Потому что разница на одной операции - 0.00000009 секунд.

Более того, если разница между StringBuilder и String.Concat на одном сложении для вас значительна - значит вы выбрали неправильную платформу и неправильный язык. Пишите на чем-нибудь более низкоуровневом, что даст вам максимальную производительность.

Comment: Вы правы, ощутимой разницы нет. Но я пишу ПО для устройства 12-летней давности. Если есть возможность использовать более производительный подход, то я хочу его использовать. Хуже не будет, а я буду знать что сделал все что мог, чтобы программа меньше тормозила.

Comment: @mirypoko тогда и тестировать производительность вам стоит на этом устройстве, а не на девелоперской машине :) JIT под разные платформы - разный. Работа с памятью на разных устройствах - разная. Результаты будут отличаться, причем непредсказуемо. И узким местом все равно окажется не еденичное сложение строк, а какая-нибудь дисковая операция.

Comment: Именно так. Правильный вывод из тестов — реальной, ощутимой разницы **нету**.

Answer (score 6):

Вы преследуете неправильную цель.

Не стоит заниматься микрооптимизациями, компилятор делает это сейчас или будет делать в будущем лучше.

Например, `string.Concat` имеет *больше* информации о том, что именно вы хотите сделать, поэтому он может быть как минимум настолько же быстрым, как и использование `StringBuilder`'а в цикле. Если он сейчас, на вашей платформе, на вашей версии JIT-компилятора медленнее, это ничего не значит, и может измениться в близком будущем. Вот, например, (неполный) [список улучшений](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/07/performance-improvements-in-net-core/) производительности, введённых недавно в .NET Core 2:

- `Queue<>.Enqueue` и `Dequeue` ускорено вдвое
- `SortedSet<>` ускорен в 600 раз
- `List<>.Add` ускорен в 1.3 раза
- `ConcurrentQueue<>` ускорена в 3.5 раза
- `string.StartsWith` ускорено вдвое

и так далее.

Таким образом, измерения мелкой производительности BCL релевантны только *на той версии* библиотеки и *в тот момент*, когда вы их проводите.

Оптимизируйте лучше алгоритмы. Прирост производительности на этом будет гораздо больше, чем выцеживание наносекунд из базовых структур данных.

Comment: +1, добавлю еще что в Core 2 вошли изменения, которые непосредственно ускорили и StringBuilder, и String.Concat, и вообще все, что работает через Buffer.Memcpy: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/9786

Answer (score 2):

Я хотел сделать заметку , хочу сказать **о памяти** (этот вопрос Вообще задаются в экзамене 70-483 Programming in C#).

'string' **(immutable)** является неизменен, непреложный означает, что если вы создаете строковый объект, то вы не можете его изменить и всегда создаете новый объект типа 'string' в памяти.

'StringBuilder' **(mutable)** является измени мой (То есть он не создает новый объект), означает что если вы создаете объект 'StringBuilder', вы можете выполнять любую операцию, например вставку, замену или добавление, без создания нового экземпляра для каждый раз. он обновит строку в одном месте в памяти, не создаст новое пространство в памяти.

То есть 'string.Concat()' он создаёт каждый раз новый объект 'string'.
это влияет на память потому что 'string' **(immutable)** является неизменен!